# Open up many files in panes at once

Tags: vim

When I need to edit multiple files, it's really a pain to have to open them one by one. Is there a way to open multiple files in VIM from the commandline?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `vim -o {file-list}` to open files horizontally splitted, or `vim -O {file-list}` to open them vertically splitted. But in your case, I always use `vim -p {file-list}` to open files in tab pages (because size of each window is nearly size of your terminal in this mode).

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
vim -O file1 file2 file3 file4 #open files side by side
vim -o file1 file2 file3 file4 #open files stacked
```